# Linq2Couchbase throwing error "Could not acquire a server"

Tags: .net, linq, couchbase

I'm using Linq2Couchbase (V 1.2.1) in a web api .net project.

My web api runs some simple queries on my local Couchbase Server (http://lcocalhost:8091) using library Linq2Couchbase and the dependant library CouchbaseNetClient (V 2.4.2).

The problem is that my **application works erratically**: sometimes it works fine, and some times it throws exception

```
An error occurred executing the N1QL query.  See the inner exception for details
```

with internal exception

```
Could not acquire a server
```

I say erratically because I have found no pattern at all on when the Couchbase server apparently can't be acquired and when it can't. I can access my server perfectly and I can run queries on it 100% of the time.

The funny thing is that if I don't use Linq2Couchbase and use directly  CouchbaseNetClient instead, I don't get this problem.

I'd prefer to use LinQ whenever possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error indicates that the Couchbase SDK (which the linq provider is using) cannot connect to the server (or maintain a connection). The best thing to do would be to enable logging and try to identify how the client got into that state. It could be that the query service is down or perhaps something between the client and server is causing an issue (firewall/hhtp debugger?).

Answer (score 0):

when my server encounter this problem, I recreate all indexes, and restart computer, sometimes it works.

my server has two network card, I'm not sure if this is the result.

do you solve the problem?

Comment: Nop, I haven't found a solution. I just stopped using LinQ2Couchbase and stuck to using normal N1Ql queries